# ASP.NET Transferring data to postgresql

Tags: asp.net, postgresql

I can't understand why the data is not transferred to the database

There is a controller

```
public class PeopleController : Controller
    {
 private readonly string ConnectionString = "Host=localhost;Port=5432;Database=CrudDb;Username=postgres;Password=12345;Maximum Pool Size=100";

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Create(People people)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                IDbConnection con;
    
                string insertQuery = "INSERT INTO people(name, phone) VALUES(@Name, @Phone)";
                con = new NpgsqlConnection(ConnectionString);
                con.Open();
                con.Execute(insertQuery, people);
                con.Close();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(people);
        }

    }
```

There is a model for her

```
public class People
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int Phone { get; set; }


    }
```

And there is a page

```
 <form asp-action="Contacts">
                    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="Name" class="col-form-label">Имя</label>
                        <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="Phone" class="col-form-label">Телефон </label>
                        <input asp-for="Phone" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Phone" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group p-4">    
                        <input type="submit" value="Создать" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm" /> &emsp;
                        
                    </div>
                </form>
```

It does not issue any errors, I enter data on the page, but this data is not transmitted to the database. From libraries, Dapper and Npgsql are connected

Comment: Completely OT: a phone number is not an int - an int cannot have leading zeroes

Comment: con.Execute returns an integer that is the number of rows inserted by the executed command. Please catch this value and tell us what is it. Side note, are you sure that the controller action has been called? Can you check with the debugger what values are present on the People instance passed to your controller action?

Comment: To me it seems that you are not calling that action Create. I would change your page with this line _<form asp-controller="People" asp-action="Create" method="post">_